Foreign keys/Join columns and Join tables are not created by Doctrine in Symfony 5+
In the title I mentioned both Foreign keys and Join tables. In this case, to begin with, I am concerned with Foreign keys. But anyway a Join table is just multiple Foreign keys in a table. It seems that in Symfony 5+ (so above 4), the Doctrine program doesn't handle the relations as it used to?
I mention this divide because from what I remember (I haven't worked in a long time and at that time I used Symfony 4) in the previous version(s) there was no problem. The code below is in version 5 but it could be 6 and the same result would happen.
So basically there are 2 entities, User and Video. First User.php:
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`user`')]
class User// implements EntityInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private string $fingerprint;

    #[OneToMany(targetEntity: "App\Entity\Video", mappedBy: "user")]
    private ?ArrayCollection $videos = null;

    ...
}

and the second file Video.php:
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: VideoRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`video`')]
class Video// implements EntityInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $filename = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    private \DateTimeInterface $date;

    // #[ORM\Column(name: "id_user", type: "integer")]
    #[ManyToOne(targetEntity: "App\Entity\User", inversedBy: "videos")]
    #[JoinColumn(name: "id_user", referencedColumnName: "id")]
    private User $user;

    ...
}

Now if I'm not mistaken, I've pefectly respected the annotations of Doctrine for 5+ Symfony versions according to this.
And I should obtain something like in the documentation including the Foreign key mention ALTER TABLE Feature ADD FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES Product(id);  (adapted to my tables).
But the fact is that when I run: php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
I do not get the Foreign key part:
CREATE TABLE `user` (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, fingerprint VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE `video` (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, filename VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, date DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB;

What is worse is that if I artificially create the Foreign key myself, then the command php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql will want to drop it.
What am I missing here...? Thank you in advance for your help. In the meantime I guess I'll try to go develop in Symfony 4.4, and the annotations will of course be different (comment style) for it to work.
PS: it's not the id_user vs. user_id, I already tried it didn't change anything.
If I uncomment #[ORM\Column(name: "id_user", type: "integer")] in User.php I will get a column, but no Foreign key constraint... so it's not a solution.
Here is my entire User class:
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

use App\Entity\EntityInterface;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`user`')]
class User
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private string $fingerprint;

    #[OneToMany(targetEntity: VideoRepository::class, mappedBy: "user")]
    private ?ArrayCollection $videos = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->videos = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(int $id): static
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFingerprint(): string
    {
        return $this->fingerprint;
    }

    public function setFingerprint(string $fingerprint): static
    {
        $this->fingerprint = $fingerprint;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVideos(): ArrayCollection
    {
        return $this->videos;
    }

    // https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/stable/index.html
    public function addVideo(Video $video): static
    {
        if ($this->videos == null) {
            $this->videos = new ArrayCollection();
            $this->videos->add($video);
       }
        $this->videos->add($video);

        return $this;
    }

    public function setVideos(Video $videos): static
    {
        $this->videos = new ArrayCollection($videos);
        return $this;
    }
}


Can you post one of your class completely without removing stuff (except methods) ? I don't understand why your class name is User// and why do you use the ORM namespace in some attributes and not the other ? (like id & ManyToOne

It was previously the same namespace/classname before, it was one of the solutions I tried, but whether I write VideoRepository::class or "App\Entity\User" in the annotation I get the same result, so it wasn't a solution. I will edit the OP and post the User class entirely. The class name isn't User// the two dashes are a comment :) yes I should have put a blank space there.

Try replacing #[OneToMany by #[ORM\OneToMany and same thing with ManyToOne and JoinColumn attribute

Believe it or not but I found it before reading your comment. I was trying to change the annotations in a parallel 4.4 version project and I noticed that I had used #[ORM\ everywhere except for the relationships. And I just tried and it worked so that was it! Thank you.

Glad it worked, that's what I meant earlier when I said "why do you use the ORM namespace in some attributes and not the other ? (like id & ManyToOne"

Ah! Sorry I misunderstood, I thought you were referring to something else. Yes indeed, why would I be doing that? Because when you look at the documentation, there isn't the ORM namespace prefixed, but when you generate an entity with the console it puts the prefix. So when I copied the documentation to create the relationship I didn't see (at first, now I see) that I had to add the ORM namespace.

As I said it's been a while I haven't coded, over a year, so this explains that. I had simply forgotten to mention the ORM\ prefix in the relationships. It is so obvious when you finally see it. Here are the updated lines:
User.php
#[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: "App\Entity\Video", mappedBy: "user")]

Video.php
#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: "App\Entity\User", inversedBy: "videos")]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "id_user", referencedColumnName: "id")]

And now php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql returns the correct SQL:
CREATE TABLE `user` (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, fingerprint VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE `video` (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, id_user INT DEFAULT NULL, filename VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, date DATETIME NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_7CC7DA2C6B3CA4B (id_user), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE `video` ADD CONSTRAINT FK_7CC7DA2C6B3CA4B FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES `user` (id);

